# How to selectively load hibernate entity while still initializing (not loading) lazy collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

Consider following simple entity model

```
class Order{
  int id;
  String description;
  //one to one eager load with join column specified
  Detail details;
  //one to many lazy load with mapped by specified
  Collection<Item> items;
}

class Detail{
}

class Item{
  String name;
  //reference to order
}
```

Now, let's say the requirement is to load all the orders with item details by some criteria (e.g. description matching something). Simple, i write a hql like "from Order where description...". This loads 1000 entities for example and item collection is lazy loaded. I force load them within the session by calling size.

This of course led to a N+1 problem so i decided to use batch fetching for items. Just added the batch size annotation on item collection and much fewer queries as expected.

However, i am not interested in 'detail' at all but since it is a one to one eager load, there is one query per Order to load this always. I simply want to do away with these queries.

To solve this, i try to do a select without details but i am not sure how to include items (collection) in the query so that it is loaded exactly in the same way as if i was selecting all (that is, lazy loaded which then can utilize batch size on later calls). Some suggestions are to use join in the where clause but that initializes my collection with empty array list (and not with PersistentBag as is the case with Lazy loading).

Looking for solutions.

Comment: Why not making `Detail` lazily loaded?

Comment: There is other parts of the application which rely on default (eager) loading. Moreover, all solutions to make 1-1 a lazy load are non-trivial( bytecode instrumentation etc.) and i don't want to risk breaking the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is the following:

- Create a POJO which will contain a query result. Example:

  ```
  public class OrderResult {
      private String description;
      private String itemName;
      // ... more fields, if any

      public OrderResult(String desc, String itemName) {
          this.description = desc;
          this.itemName = itemName;
      }

      // getters & setters
  }
  ```
- Create a JPQL query using a constructor expression as:

  ```
  List<OrderResult> resultList = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT NEW OrderResult(o.description, i.name) FROM Order o JOIN o.items i where <condition>", OrderResult.class).getResultList();
  ```

So you'll get a list of instances of `OrderResult` containing only the information you're interested in.

NOTE 1: You're talking of HQL, but HQL is the Hibernate specific legacy query language. As Hibernate is an implementation of JPA, and you tagged your question with JPA, this solution should work in your environment too.

NOTE 2: In the solution, I am using the so called constructor expression of JPQL which is defined using `NEW` in the select clause. The argument to the `NEW` operator must be a fully qualified class name,e.g., if you put the `OrderResult` class in a package `com.mycompany.myproject.order`, then the expression should look like:

```
SELECT NEW com.mycompany.myproject.order.OrderResult(...) FROM ...
```

NOTE 3: This is just to give you a hint how to implement the solution and should be considered as pseodo code.

Comment: But your solution leaves out the items collection from the consideration. I want Items in the order details and as far as i have understood, i can not include the collections in the constructor arguments. Or am I missing something?